# git push - client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer

Tags: github

I have encountered this problem recently and I have never been able to find a coherent explanation or solution.

When attempting to push *a specific branch* to github, I am receiving the following error:

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I am able to push other branches fine, so it cannot be a network error.

I vaguely remember in the past getting an error like this when I mistakenly included something like an auth token in the code. However, that is not the case here.

I am also not pushing any particularly large files (except maybe `package-lock.json`?)

How I can I find out more about what is causing github to reject my push?

**Update**

After a dozen tries over about 20 minutes the push was finally accepted. I am still curious whether there is an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there could be a number of reasons for this to occur, but in my case it was some issue on our VPN. I encountered the issue again today, hopped off the VPN and pushed again, and it immediately worked.

Comment: thanks for this. In my case, this error occurred not during a push, but during a clone, and your solution (of getting off the VPN) worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There is simple solution for this. Go to git bash and just follow the steps,

(1) vim .ssh/config

(2) insert- ServerAliveInterval 60

(3) close vim by Esc ---> ZZ